# Алгоритм вычисления даты

Tags: php

Есть две даты, как определить методами php сколько от одной даты до другой в часах днях и месяцах. Думаю очень часто встречающаяся проблема, подскажите алгоритм.

Сам попробовал через mktime - **запутался**

Comment: Какого вида ваша дата?

Comment: чч дд мм - по 2 цифры

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Date and Time](http://php.net/datetime)

```
$date = new DateTime("2012-12-21"); 
$interval = $date->diff(new DateTime("now")); 
echo $interval->format(($interval->invert ? "Осталось" : "Прошло")." лет: %y; месяцев: %m; дней: %d; часов: %h; минут: %i; секунд: %s");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$start = '12 02 12';
$end = '18 02 12';
$startExp = explode(' ', $start);
$endExp = explode(' ', $end);
$startTS = mktime(0, 0, 0, $startExp[1], $startExp[0], $startExp[2]); // timestamp начала
$endTS = mktime(0, 0, 0, $endExp[1], $endExp[0], $endExp[2]); // timestamp конца
var_dump($startTS, $endTS);
```

Дальше сами.

Comment: @exec в условии были "часы" "дни" "месяцы" а не "день" "месяц" "год"
и думаю основная проблема как раз и заключалась в том чтобы распарсить интервал времени обратно.

Comment: Однако. когда я спросил какого вида дата, там не было указано время.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getTimeDifference($cur_time, $time) {
    $difference = abs($time – $cur_time);
    $return['days'] = floor($difference / 86400);
    $return['hours'] = floor($difference / 3600) % 24;
    $return['minutes'] = floor($difference / 60) % 60;

    return $return;
}
```

Тестируем функцию:

```
print_r(getTimeDifference(1242902278, 1242803038));
```